# Comedy mystery short story involving an inept detective, stolen diamonds, and a baby's rattle

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I remember reading this as a short story in an anthology, probably in the early 1990s. My parents had a lot of books with crime stories in them, as well as humor anthologies, so that unfortunately doesn't narrow it down much. The protagonist is a somewhat nutty detective who has been assigned (or assigned himself?) to a case involving stolen diamonds. Unfortunately, the only details which are firm in my mind are that a) at one point he triumphantly smashes a vase, claiming that the diamonds were baked into the obvious fake, only to be told that it was a priceless antique vase (Ming?) that was worth more than the lost diamonds and b) that the eventual reveal is that the thieves took a baby's rattle, opened it up, and stuck the diamonds in there. I want to say there was some description of "dirty gray rocks" either from them having found the original beads from the rattle, or as a description of how the diamonds looked when liberated from the rattle.

I do remember there was at least one illustration in the story, showing the detective holding up either the vase or the rattle, with a vacant look on his face. I want to say that he had blond curls, and was dressed as a pastiche of Sherlock Holmes costumes with a deerstalker hat and meerschaum pipe.

I'm certain it's not *[Cam Jansen and the Mystery of the Stolen Diamonds](https://forgottenstoriesweb.wordpress.com/2019/09/15/cam-jansen-and-the-mystery-of-the-stolen-diamonds/)*, which involves a similar reveal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*P. Moran Diamond Hunter* by Percival Wilde looks like possibility. I found some snippets in the Google Books record of *[Spellbinders in Suspense](https://books.google.com/books?id=fXAZxYBr6KkC)* By Alfred Hitchcock:

> He says, “Moran, do you realize what have you done? You have smashed
> a sang de beef vase right out of the finest Ming period! The
> Metropolitan Museum tried to buy that vase from me but I would not
> sell it, and the leaves of the plant are turned away from the light
> because it is an artificial plant!”

> I can see that the pebbles, which were round and small and about the
> same size obviously came from the baby's rattle — so obviously that
> nobody thought of it excepting you — and that Hewitt made the
> substitution in the dark, taking it for granted we wouldn't give the
> pebbles a second glance; but there must have been clues which told you
> who was the guilty man long before that.

Comment: [Available for loan at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/hitchckspellbind00alfr/page/182/mode/2up)

Comment: Thank you! We had a few of those *Spellbinders* books in the house, so that's the likely source.

Comment: Congratulations on 2000 reputation :-)

Comment: @SeanDuggan It's not the first time you've asked [a story-id question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12571/3003) about this anthology!

Comment: Evidently, this book needs a reread...